# How to save two dates, one using local date and one in UTC

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

**I have the need to store both local time as per users timezone and UTC time in a transaction table using core data**

What I want is as follows

createDate should reflect the users local timezone, in this case I am in **China so GMT+8**

createDateUtc should represent the same timestamp but in **UTC**

I have tried various formatters but for some reason I cannot get the result I want

Here are my two formatters as you can see I tried using timezone as well but it still did not set the date to UTC.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterWithTz = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
  [dateFormatterWithTz setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];  

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
  [dateFormatterUtc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];  
  //[dateFormatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

here is how I create the date variables

```
 NSDate *createdDateUtc = [NSDate date];   
 NSDate *createdDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] sinceDate:createdDateUtc];
```

Here is what the array looks like which is incorrect as you can see it created my Utc date as my local date and pushed the created date to tomorrow and still using the same time offset, the issue should be that my UTC date is set to local time but I cannot figure out how to make it UTC so that my created date gets calculated correctly from that

```
createdDate = "2016-12-25T03:19:38+08:00";  
createdDateUtc = "2016-12-24T19:19:38+08:00";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide timeZone for date formater

for **local timeZone** try this

```
NSDateFormatter *formate =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *strToday =[formate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

and For UTC timezone set **UTC timezone** like this

```
NSDateFormatter *formate =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *strToday =[formate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

hope this will help you.